# Icon images not displaying in an inline-block fashion

Tags: html, css, position

I have a small bug that is driving me nuts. I have three social media icons that I want to display in an `inline-block` fashion. My code is correct, as far as I can see. I even made a snippet and it looks to be correct. I looked in my dev tools and do not see anything causing this issue. It is happening on my site in a viewport of 640px or less. This is making it hard to see what is wrong in the dev tools because of the small screen.

Does anyone see anything standing out? Please view the page in a viewport of 640px or less.

[Click here to see live](http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index)

```css
.nav-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.7s;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.nav-panel-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  overflow: auto;
  /* smooth scrolling on touch devices */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
#nav-social-container {
  bottom: 8%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
#nav-social-title {
  font-size: .8em;
}
#nav-social-icons {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.nav-social-icon {
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-social-icon:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-social-icon:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-panel-container">
  <div class="nav-panel-content">
    <div id="nav-social-container">
      <div id="nav-social-title">DON'T BE SHY, LET'S GET SOCIAL.</div>
      <div id="nav-social-icons"><span class="nav-social-icon"><a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/facebookBlack.png" alt="facebook" height="30px" width="30px"></a></span><span class="nav-social-icon"><a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/twitterBlack.png" alt="twitter" height="30px" width="30px"></a></span>
        <span
        class="nav-social-icon">
          <a href="http://linkedin.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/linkedInBlack.png" alt="linkedIn" height="30px" width="30px">
          </a>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, by the way, it is in my mobile menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `<span>` tags - these are `display:inline` - change them to `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: I guess I had the `display: inline-block;` in the id one instead of the class, but changing this makes these display as blocks instead.

Comment: The container has the class of "inline-block", but the span elements are still "inline" - if you set them to "block" you will need to set a width and float:left, if you set them to "inline-block" it will set the width based on the block size.

Comment: Just looked again - you have the width of the span elements set to 100% - remove this.

Comment: ok I did this `.nav-social-icon img {
 display: inline-block;
}` and still nothing.

Comment: It looks fine on my screen? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve!

Comment: I want the icons to be on one line. I uploaded an image to show what I am getting on my desktop screen and my phone

Comment: You still have the container set as "inline block" - change this to block and the elements inside of it to "inline-block" without setting the width of the spans at 100%. The padding seems to be overflowing it too.

Comment: Awesome that got it to display on one line. Do you see why my nav-social-container isn't taking on the `bottom` positioning I am giving it? `#nav-social-container {
 bottom: 8%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 10%;
}`

Comment: Because your     nav-panel-content is overflowing before. Set this element to     overflow:hidden and it should solve your issue.

Comment: The hidden did not help.

Comment: Set your position accordingly after you've set the containers overflow to hidden.